# Nativescript - ActivityIndicator not working for a specific chunk of code

Tags: nativescript

I'd like to display an activity-indicator displayed when I do a long process.

I set a model busy flag to true.

I then call a method that returns a Promise - when the promise calls resolve, I then set the busy flag to false in my 'then' handler.

When I wait for the promise to resolve, I expect the Activity Indicator animation to be displayed but it's not.

I checked and made sure the UI set up is correct and it works.

The work that's being done is using nativescript-calendar plugin - I'm adding a few calendar entries.

I commented out  the work that's being done and just went to sleep for a little bit and then called resolve() and the animation worked.

So the Activity Indicator and the Promise mechanism is setup correctly - it's something this plug-in is doing that's causing the AI not to display.

What could cause such a behavior?

I actually edited the Promise work code - put to sleep for about 1 second and then started the calendar work. I see the AI for 1 second and then it freezes.

So it looks like the calendar writes is causing the AI to freeze.

I was under the understanding that Promise work is done in the background and should not effect foreground animation.

Answer (score 0):

I've had a similar issue when using SQLite.

As you haven't explicitly stated that your running the calendar in a worker I am assuming your keeping it in the UI thread (main thread).

Any large amount of work done in the UI thread will cause noticeable lag/delays. So for example you call the activity-indicator then call a process that maxes out the thread, the process finishes the activity indicator goes to be drawn on the screen but then is hidden straight away before it is displayed as the process is finished.

The ideal way to solve this is to move the calendar writes code into a worker (multithread your app) and on success message turn off the activity-indicator.

Comment: I'm doing all the calendar work in a Promise. My understanding was that Promises allows async operation - so the body of the Promise is being processed in the background...but looks like that was a misunderstanding on my part.

Comment: @dashman yep so my understanding of promises is that it basically inserts code into the execution queue when it's ready.  By default js is a single thread language (like other popular languages). If you want to do stuff in a different thread your going to have to use a worker